# SQL Server query for grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table with 2 columns `plateno` and `alerts`.

table `Data`

```
plateno    alerts
  A         1
  B         2
  C         2
  A         3
  B         2
  A         4
  A         1
```

Now I want to get the result like this:

```
alerts->   1  2  3  4
---------------------------
A          2  0  1  1
B          0  2  0  0
C          0  1  0  0
```

I mean 'A' has two alerts of type '1',1 alert of type '3' and '4'...and so on..

Here is my query I am trying with

```
Select count(alert) 
from mytable 
group by plateno
```

Comment: Where's the SQL query you're trying to get working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :-

```
Select plateno,[1],[2],[3],[4]
from 
(
 Select plateno,alerts from Sample
)p
pivot 
(
 count(alerts)
 for alerts in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
)pvt
```

Demo [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1f49/1)

Answer (score 2):

If you have unknown number of values for the column `Alert`, a *dynamic sql* is much more preferred,

```
DECLARE @colList AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @sqlStatement AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @colList = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(alerts) 
                    FROM data
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')


SET @sqlStatement = 'SELECT plateno,' + @colList + ' 
             FROM 
             (
                SELECT plateno, alerts 
                FROM data
             ) dta
             pivot 
             (
                COUNT(alerts)
                FOR alerts IN (' + @colList + ')
             ) pvt '

EXECUTE(@sqlStatement)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3233e/5)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║ PLATENO ║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 3 ║ 4 ║
╠═════════╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║ A       ║ 2 ║ 0 ║ 1 ║ 1 ║
║ B       ║ 0 ║ 2 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║
║ C       ║ 0 ║ 1 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║
╚═════════╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

Comment: [see here for other example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/75889/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT plateno
,SUM(CASE alerts WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [1]
,SUM(CASE alerts WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2]
,SUM(CASE alerts WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [3]
,SUM(CASE alerts WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [4]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY plateno
```

Output:

```
╔═════════╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║ PLATENO ║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 3 ║ 4 ║
╠═════════╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║ A       ║ 2 ║ 0 ║ 1 ║ 1 ║
║ B       ║ 0 ║ 2 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║
║ C       ║ 0 ║ 1 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║
╚═════════╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38f0a/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select plateno,sum([1]) as [1],sum([2]) as [2],sum([3]) as [3],sum([4]) as [4]
from 
(
 Select plateno,
  case when alert=1 then 1 else 0 end as [1],
  case when alert=2 then 1 else 0 end as [2],
  case when alert=3 then 1 else 0 end as [3],
  case when alert=4 then 1 else 0 end as [4]
 from planet

 )z
group by plateno
```

**SQL fiddle** [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c37ec/15)